# Draggable into Sortable as Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to create using jquery a draggable list into a sortable list.

Everything works, except when using CSS to transform this list into a grid. As soon as everything is displayed as a grid, the draggable into the sortable stops to work.

My **HTML** is:

```
<ul id="sortable2">
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">A</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">B</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">C</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">D</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">3</li>
</ul>
```

My page **SCRIPT** is:

```
$(function() {
   $("#sortable").sortable();
   $("#sortable2 li").draggable({
      connectToSortable: "#sortable",
      helper: "clone"
   });
});
```

And the **CSS** I've added to make both UL display as grid is:

```css
#sortable {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 450px;
}
#sortable li {
  margin: 3px 3px 3px 0;
  padding: 1px;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 90px;
  font-size: 4em;
  text-align: center;
}
#sortable2 {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 450px;
}
#sortable2 li {
  margin: 3px 3px 3px 0;
  padding: 1px;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 90px;
  font-size: 4em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Any ideas?

I'm using jquery-ui.css, jquery-ui.js and jquery.min.js.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is occurring is because the children `li` elements are floated.

When an element is floated, it is essentially [removed from the normal document flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats), and in this case results in the parent element collapsing upon itself with a height of `0`:

[image]

As a result, you can't drop elements into the `#sortable` element because it doesn't have a height.

The most common work-around is to use [a clearfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix) to prevent the parent element from collapsing.

Either add `overflow: auto` to the container element [(example)](http://jsfiddle.net/Lsgtd3eb/):

```
ul {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

or use a pseudo-element [(example)](http://jsfiddle.net/n9ycebzt/):

```
ul:after {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

---

Alternatively, you could also just remove `float: left` from the `li` elements and set their `display` to `inline-block` instead. Additionally, `vertical-align: top` should be added to resolve a minor alignment issue when dragging the elements [(example)](http://jsfiddle.net/gfkgw2ee/):

```
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate. It worked.I ended up using this: #sortable:after { clear:both; content:'.'; display:block; height:0; line-height:0; font-size:0; visibility:hidden; padding:0; margin:0; }